# How I can install Aegisub in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 and want to install Aegisub on it.How can I do it.I have tried to installed but failed.+

Answer (score 6):

Aegisub is currently unavailable in the official Ubuntu repositories [due to a bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=873327), although you can install it from the [Alexander Pozdnyakov repository](https://launchpad.net/~alex-p/+archive/ubuntu/aegisub):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alex-p/aegisub
sudo apt install aegisub
```

If you want to compile it, read this thread: [Why is Aegisub no longer available in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030336/why-is-aegisub-no-longer-available-in-ubuntu)

Comment: While these commands might answer the question you still might consider adding a few explanatory sentences as this increases the value of your answer for other users.

Answer (score 0):

Aegisub is available in Ubuntu Software Center since Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal, but it’s old. At the moment, the latest version is 3.0.4 and it’s available for download at the given links: http://ftp.aegisub.org/pub/releases/aegisub_3.0.4-1_i386.deb
http://ftp.aegisub.org/pub/releases/aegisub_3.0.4-1_amd64.deb

Once downloaded, you can install it in Ubuntu 13.10, Ubuntu 13.04, Ubuntu 12.04 and their derivatives such as Linux Mint and Elementary by running below commands in terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T):

```
  sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/aegisub_*.deb; sudo apt-get -f install
```

Or you can directly double-click to install the Deb if there’s no dependency problem.

Comment: doesn't work on ubuntu 18.04. It says it requires libfftw3-3 libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libhunspell-1.3-0, but there is no install candidate for libhunspell-1.3-0

Answer (score 0):

i'm using elementary OS / ubuntu 16.04 (xenial),
i just using

```
sudo apt install aegisub
```

and still working . .

Comment: Does not work in Ubuntu 18.04 -> `E: Unable to locate package aegisub`

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Install Meson [via package manager](https://mesonbuild.com/Quick-guide.html#installation-using-package-manager) or [via Python](https://mesonbuild.com/Quick-guide.html#installation-using-python)

Step 2: Install Aegisub

```
mkdir -v $HOME/aegisub_build && cd $HOME/aegisub_build
git clone -b meson --recursive https://github.com/TypesettingTools/Aegisub.git
cd Aegisub/
meson builddir && cd builddir
ninja
sudo ninja install
```

Step 3: If you want, you can delete the build directory

```
rmdir $HOME/aegisub_build
```